# Prove that X is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a topological space. Is it true that if $X = A\cup B$, $A\cap B = \emptyset$ and $A$ and $B$ are both connected, then $X$ is connected?

Comment: If you are claiming what I think you are claiming, then yes, but there are a couple of typos in your question you should fix before I can be sure.

Comment: I'm sure (s)he means $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$...

Comment: Did you mean $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $X=U\cup V$, with $U,V$ open disjoint sets. Since $A\subseteq X$ is connected, either $A\subseteq U$ or $A\subseteq V$. Same thing for $B$. Since $U,V$ are disjoint and $A,B$ are not, either $A,B\subseteq U$ or $A,B\subseteq V$. But $X=A\cup B$, and so $U=\varnothing$ or $V=\varnothing$. Therefore $X$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Let $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. This satisfies your requirements but is not connected.